# Number of cores a Python script is using

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing` module to parallelize the script but not sure if it is using all the available cores. Is there a straightforward way to find it?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time

def fibonacci(n):
    sequence = [0, 1]
    while len(sequence) < n:  
        next_number = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]  
        sequence.append(next_number)  
    return np.array(sequence)  # Convert the sequence to a NumPy array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    last_result = None
    n = 100
    for i in range(0, n): 
        result = fibonacci(i)
        #print([result])
    
    U = time.time() - start_time
    print("Elapsed time =", U)
```

Comment: This creates a multiprocessing pool but does nothing with it, therefore it only runs in a single process using one core at a time.

Comment: How can I adapt the code so that it uses all the available cores?

Comment: - use the following code to get the number of cores:

`num_of_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()`

`print('Number of CPUS: ', num_of_cpus)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main code to use all cores may look something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(fibonacci, range(0, n))

    result = results[-1]
    
    U = time.time() - start_time
    print("Elapsed time =", U)
```

Be aware that this is not necessarily faster than the single process. Due to the overhead of multiprocessing it may need some fine tuning (especially by setting a chunk size for `map`).

Answer (score 0):

you have only initialized multiprocessing pool but did not utalized to use all the cpus or even multiprocessing instead use the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

last_result = None
    n = 100
    results = []
    for i in range(0, n): 
        results.append(pool.apply_async(fibonacci, (i,)))
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    U = time.time() - start_time
    print("Elapsed time =", U)
```

the `pool.apply_async()` method call `fibonacci()` function in parallel method

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to accurately monitor CPU usage especially in a case like this where the *fibonacci()* function is short-lived. However, if you use the appropriate multiprocessing techniques you can be assured that your system's capabilities will be fully utilised.

Here's something similar to OP's code that will make full use of available CPUs:

```
from numpy import array, ndarray
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import perf_counter
from os import cpu_count

N = 100

def get_cpu_count() -> int:
    if (count := cpu_count()) is not None:
        return count
    return 1

def fibonacci(n: int) -> ndarray:
    sequence = [0, 1]
    for _ in range(n-2):  
        sequence.append(sequence[-1]+sequence[-2])  
    return array(sequence)

def main() -> None:
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map_async(fibonacci, range(N), chunksize=max(1, N//get_cpu_count())).wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    main()
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
Duration=0.2697s
```

**Note:**

The calculation for chunk size is reasonable for many cases but not all