# Running Python scripts on multiple cores

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have 12 Python scripts. I am trying to run scripts 1-3 on core 1, 4-6 on core 2, 7-9 on core 3, and 10-12 on core 4 but it's not saving the data. My laptop has 4 logical cores. I present the codes below.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def run_script(script_number):
    # Define the CPU core affinity for each script
    cpu_affinities = {
        1: [0],
        2: [1],
        3: [2],
        4: [3],
    }

    # Set the CPU affinity for the current process
    os.sched_setaffinity(0, cpu_affinities[script_number])

    # Execute the script
    script_file = f"script_{script_number}.py"
    os.system(f"python {script_file}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a multiprocessing pool with 4 processes
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

    # Submit the scripts to the pool
    for script_number in range(1, 13):
        pool.apply_async(run_script, args=(script_number,))

    # Close the pool and wait for all processes to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The scripts `1-12` are

```
import numpy as np
def fibonacci(n):
    sequence = [0, 1]
    while len(sequence) < n:  
        next_number = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]  
        sequence.append(next_number)  
    return sequence


n = 3
for i in range(0,n): 
    result = fibonacci(i)
    print(result)
    
    with open("1.txt", 'a') as f: #the file number will change accordingly
        f.writelines('\n') 
        f.write(str(result))
    print(result)
```

Comment: Why do you think that they are not running?

Comment: I don't know but may be I am not assigning the cores correctly to Python scripts. It's running but not generating the output. I have edited the post to include this information.

Comment: Where are you looking for the output data? Is the data saved if you just call `run_script` directly without `multiprocessing`?

Comment: This is a variation of your earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76449628/number-of-cores-a-python-script-is-using/76449960#76449960 Maybe you should step back and re-think exactly what you're trying to achieve. Sounds like you've got 12 scripts all of which are identical apart from the output filename. You should think about parameterising that and also wonder why you're importing numpy if you're not going to use it

Comment: That's a good idea. But I also want to try run scripts on different cores.

Comment: @KeplerNick123 How do you propose to make your code portable? Remember... *os.sched_setaffinity()* is not available on all platforms

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question...All I am looking for is that the code will help me to redistribute running of different scripts on different cores.

Comment: You might look for gnu parallel. It will invoke your python scripts on different cores in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your verbal description of how you want to assign cores to scripts does not quite match your actual code. But I will go by your verbal description: You are adding to the pool's input task queue the numbers 1 through 12 in order. Tasks will be executed by the pool processes in the order placed on the queue. So the first 4 scripts to be executed will be 1 through 4. Yet you say you want scripts 1 through 3 to run on the same core. You have just confined the first 4 scripts to be executing on cores 1 and 2. That is clearly not optimal parallelism.

First, I don't know why you care what cores scripts are run on. Confining a script to run on a particular core could potentially hurt performance. That said, I will assume that your decision as to which core a script is to run on was somewhat arbitrary and, as I have stated, was not really the best assignment. So instead we just ensure that each pool process is confined to a single core and we don't really care which pool process executes which script. **Does that work for you?** In this way we still ensure that when 4 scripts are being executed in parallel, each script has been confined to its own distinct core for execution. If that works for you, then I would suggest that instead of creating a new process with your `os.system` call to execute each of your 12 scripts, why not just import the script?

```py
import multiprocessing
import os
from importlib import import_module

def init_pool_processes(core_number):
    with core_number.get_lock():
        core = core_number.value
        core_number.value += 1
    os.sched_setaffinity(0, [core])

def run_script(script_number):
    # Execute the script
    import_module(f"script_{script_number}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a multiprocessing pool with 4 processes
    # assigning to each process its own CPU affinity:
    core_number = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(core_number,))

    # Submit the scripts to the pool
    pool.map(run_script, range(1, 13))

    # Close the pool and wait for all processes to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I thought CPU affinity was inherited. Is that not so?

Comment: @DarkKnight That's a good question so I wrote a small program to find out and it appears it is actually inherited.  Even so, why would the OP prefer to create a new process rather than just importing the module? Anyway, I have updated my answer with this newly found info. Thanks!

Comment: The way OP is approaching this is very mysterious. I can only assume that there's no real functional requirement and that it's merely a learning exercise

Comment: @DarkKnight I would agree.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to distribute your scripts over some cores, you should use gnu parallel. There is no need to use a python script, which takes care of assigning your Fibonacci scripts to certain cores. The command in your command line is as follows:

`parallel --jobs 4 python fibonacci.py {1} ::: 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt ... 12.txt`

Note, that this solution requires your Fibonacci script to accept one command line argument. For handling command line inputs, you could use the *[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)* library.

Comment: Also try removing `--jobs 4`. It will often Do What You Want(TM).